# Out of bounds memory address in the middle of 2D array?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

First off, sorry about the title. I wasn't really too sure how to phrase it.

In C, I have a 2D string array, declared and allocated as follows:

```
char ** args = malloc(50*(num_args+1));
for (int i = 0; i < num_args+1; i++){
    args[i] = malloc(50);
```

I am using this in sort of a "rudimentary shell" type program, mimicking some of the features of bash, hence the num_args variable.

Compiled and run on multiple machines, the address at args[4] is always out of bounds. Here is the relevant gdb output:

```
(gdb) print args[0]
$2 = 0x609140 "gcc"
(gdb) print args[1]
$3 = 0x609180 ""
(gdb) print args[2]
$4 = 0x6091c0 ""
(gdb) print args[3]
$5 = 0x609200 ""
(gdb) print args[4]
$6 = 0x636367 <Address 0x636367 out of bounds>
(gdb) print args[5]
$7 = 0x609280 ""
```

As you can see, addresses before and after args[4] are valid. How can this one address be out of bounds?

The entire function where this code is used is [here](http://pastebin.com/iRh3N3x3) and below:

```
void parse(const char * command){
    // first parse built-ins (ie, not a call to the OS)
    if (strcmp(command, "history") == 0){
        show_history();
        return;
    }
    if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0){
        exit(0);
    }

    hist_add(command);

    // copy 'command' into arg_string, while ignoring any possible comments
    char * arg_str;
    int num_args = 1;
    arg_str = malloc(strlen(command));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(command); i++){
        if (command[i] == '#' || command[i] == '\n') break;
        if (command[i] == ' ') num_args++;
        arg_str[i] = command[i];
    }

    // split arg_str into a string array where each string is an argument
    // to the command
    char ** args = malloc(num_args+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_args+1; i++){
        args[i] = malloc(50);
    }
    int tokens = 0;
    const char token = ' ';
    char * next = strtok(arg_str, &token);
    while (next != NULL){
        strcpy(args[tokens++], next);
        next = strtok(NULL, &token);
        if (next == NULL)
            args[tokens] = (char *)NULL;
    }

    exec_command(args);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `num_args` for the debugging statements you show?

Comment: Something copied the letters 'ccg' (or perhaps 'gcc') over your pointer.  The code you show isn't the source of the trouble.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that while debugging the program was in the middle of parsing through a string of text. "gcc" is there intentionally. The code for the full function shows where num_args comes from (pastebin link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the fact that it's *not* a 2D array.  Instead, `args` contains a pointer to the first element of a 1D array of pointers, and each of those elements can itself point to an element of a 1D array of `char` (this is often called a "ragged array", because those 1D arrays can be of different lengths).

So the reason that the one address `args[4]` can be out-of-bounds, even though `args[3]` and `args[5]` are not, is that the three pointers `args[3]`, `args[4]` and `args[5]` are completely independent values.

It is quite likely that `args[4]` is being overwritten with an incorrect value because it actually lies outside your allocated area - you are not allocating sufficient space for the array pointed to by `args`.  Your `malloc()` call requests `num_args + 1` *bytes*, but you want sufficient space for `num_args + 1` *pointers*, each of which takes up more than one byte.  I suggest changing your `malloc()` call to:

```
char ** args = calloc(num_args + 1, sizeof args[0]);
```

(Rather than using `calloc()` you can of course multiply `num_args + 1` by `sizeof args[0]` yourself and call `malloc()`, but if you do this then you need to check to make sure that the multiplication doesn't overflow `SIZE_MAX`.  `calloc()` should handle that for you).

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer. I wasn't aware of calloc, and I'm actually quite new to manual memory management (as well as C). This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `malloc()` is the number of bytes to allocate. I'm guessing `num_args` is not sufficient to hold all the pointers of type `char *` and `50` is not sufficient given your string lengths either. I haven't looked in detail at your full code, but you probably need to do `malloc(sizeof(char *) * num_args)` to allocate all the pointers to the argument strings. Then loop through and allocate enough space for each string (if they're being copied) with `malloc(sizeof(char) * len)`, where `len` is the maximum length of the string you'll need to store.

Comment: You're right about adding `sizeof(char **) * num_args`, (or simply `(char*)` ), as a pointer to a pointer is the same size as a pointer). However, isn't the size of a char always 1 byte? I should add that the mysterious args[4] memory address is still not addressable.

Comment: What is the value of `num_args`? Because if it's less than 5, you won't have sufficient space allocated for `args[4]`.

Comment: Disregard the last part of my last message. I had edited the code on one machine, and ran the old binary on a machine I was ssh'd to. Additionally, I was thinking of the initial call to malloc as in "how many pointers should I reserve?" instead of how many bytes. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @callinyouin, no problem. Also, to answer your other question: yes, I believe `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed by the C standard to return 1, but a pointer to a char could be larger than that. Nevertheless, I think it's good practice to use `sizeof` with the appropriate type argument, if only for code clarity. Of course, `malloc(sizeof(char))` and `malloc(1)` should always be identical according to the standard, but the former looks clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a probable memory allocation error and a performance bug in the following lines:

```
arg_str = malloc(strlen(command));
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(command); i++){
```

There's often a function `strdup()` available to duplicate a string.  When it is not available, you use:

```
char *arg_str = malloc(strlen(command) + 1);
```

to allow enough space for the terminal null `'\0'` too.

The performance bug is that evaluating `strlen()` on each iteration of the loop is costly if the strings are long.  Calculate the length once and reuse that — unless the length of the string varies on each iteration.

You are not null terminating your strings; it is crucial that you do so.

```
int len = strlen(command);
int i;  // Must be in scope after the loop ends
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (command[i] == '#' || command[i] == '\n') break;
    if (command[i] == ' ') num_args++;
    arg_str[i] = command[i];
}

// i is out of scope if you use for (int i = 0;...
arg_str[i] = '\0';
```

The lack of null termination probably accounts for your other problems.  In case of doubt, print things as you go, but be careful while you don't have your strings null terminated.